# Cutted string when get value of field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Anyone can explain why when access to field only return part of string?

[image: unexplicable problem when get value of field]

Comment: Look for accessors and mutators in your model file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your CursSM model file, there may be a **attribute casting**, which override the result. Check the additional information in laravel documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand!

Model was:

```
class cursSM extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'curs_sm';
    protected $primaryKey = 'curs';

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

changed to

```
class cursSM extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'curs_sm';
}
```

now works fine!

Comment: Maybe something related with the primarykey?